# javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query JPQL Query

Tags: postgresql, rest, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ways", schema = "public", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "gid"))
public class Ways implements java.io.Serializable {
private WaysId id;

public Ways() {
}

public Ways(WaysId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "gid", column = @Column(name = "gid", unique = true)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "classId", column = @Column(name = "class_id", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "length", column = @Column(name = "length", precision = 17, scale = 17)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "name", column = @Column(name = "name")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "x1", column = @Column(name = "x1", precision = 17, scale = 17)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "y1", column = @Column(name = "y1", precision = 17, scale = 17)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "x2", column = @Column(name = "x2", precision = 17, scale = 17)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "y2", column = @Column(name = "y2", precision = 17, scale = 17)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "reverseCost", column = @Column(name = "reverse_cost", precision = 17, scale = 17)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "rule", column = @Column(name = "rule")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "toCost", column = @Column(name = "to_cost", precision = 17, scale = 17)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "maxspeedForward", column = @Column(name = "maxspeed_forward")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "maxspeedBackward", column = @Column(name = "maxspeed_backward")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "osmId", column = @Column(name = "osm_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "priority", column = @Column(name = "priority", precision = 17, scale = 17)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "theGeom", column = @Column(name = "the_geom")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "source", column = @Column(name = "source")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "target", column = @Column(name = "target"))})
        //@AttributeOverride(name = "vitesse", column = @Column(name = "vitesse", precision = 17, scale = 17))})
public WaysId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(WaysId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
@Embeddable
public class WaysId implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer gid;
private int classId;
private Double length;
private String name;
private Double x1;
private Double y1;
private Double x2;
private Double y2;
private Double reverseCost;
private String rule;
private Double toCost;
private Integer maxspeedForward;
private Integer maxspeedBackward;
private Long osmId;
private Double priority;
private Serializable theGeom;
private Integer source;
private Integer target;
}



public double convertidTolat1(Integer id) {
    Double lat = null;
    Query query = entityManager
            .createQuery("select n.id.x1 from Ways n where n.id.gid=:id");
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    lat = (Double) query.getSingleResult();
    return lat;
}


@GET
@Path("lat/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public BigDecimal getlat(@PathParam(value = "id") long id) {
    BigDecimal d = iservices.getLat(id);
    return d;
}
```

Hi every body, here is my code, i want to know what's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your query. Path expressions for Embeddables are perfectly valid in JPA. You just don't get no result for it.
Javadoc for `NoResultException` is pretty descriptive.

> Thrown by the persistence provider when Query.getSingleResult() or TypedQuery.getSingleResult() is executed on a query and there is no result to return. This exception will not cause the current transaction, if one is active, to be marked for rollback.

I would suggest wrapping getSingleResult() in a try-catch block to handle no-result case

```
Object result = null;
try {
    result = query.getSingleResult();
} catch (NoResultException e) {
    log.debug("No result forund for... ");
}
```

or to always use getResultList(), i.e.

```
List results = query.getResultList();
if (results.isEmpty()) {
    return null; // handle no-results case
} else {
    return results.get(0);
}
```

You can even sometimes go further and check DB integrity if you are expecting only one result.

```
if (results.size() > 1) {
    log.warn("Found duplicated result for...");
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say that it returns a result in the query editor of postgresql.

Comment: When i tryed what you suggest me i had this exeption:
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: No entity found for query

Comment: What is the root cause of this exception?

Comment: 22:43:38,101 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-3) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: No entity found for query
22:43:38,103 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-3) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component WaysHome for method public abstract java.math.BigDecimal interfaces.IservicesRouting.getLat(long): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: No entity found for query

Comment: I'm so sorry i make a mistake, i'm invoking a wrong method, sorry to disturb you

Comment: Please don't wrap the exception just to drop it.  Exceptions are very heavy weight objects in java that take a lot of time and cpu cycles to create.  The whole stack trace needs to be created and stored in memory for every exception.  If you are going to just ignore it you are wasting resources.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do this

```
public class BwJpaResultHelper {
public static Object getSingleResultOrNull(Query query){
    List results = query.getResultList();
    if (results.isEmpty()) return null;
    else if (results.size() == 1) return results.get(0);
    throw new NonUniqueResultException(results.size());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will be okay. it worked for me

```
public Optional<UserDO> findByUserId(String userId) {
    List<UserDO> userDOList = list(namedQuery("User.findByUserId").setParameter("theUserId", userId));
    return (userDOList.isEmpty()) ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(userDOList.get(0));
}
```